# bx cs locations not displaying location based on region

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I login into Bluemix and the origin region is `us-south`.
I issue the command `bx cs locations` and it returns `dal10 and dal12`.
I change my region using command `bx target -r eu-de` and check to see if the region is changed with `bx info`. Of course, the region is now `eu-de` as expected.

I issue the command `bx cs locations` to find the locations within this region, but the locations returned are `dal10 and dal12`, which are in region `us-south` and not a part of region `eu-de`.

How do I list the Container Services locations based on region?

Comment: I looked at the doc for "bx cs cluster-create" and location says    Available locations are:

        US-South
            dal10 [Dallas]
            dal12 [Dallas]
        EU-Central
            ams03 [Amsterdam]
            fra02 [Frankfurt]

                                  I tried to change my target region to EU-Central, but it failed.  Is EU-Central really eu-de?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different regions types to consider. One is the overall Bluemix region. The other is the IBM Bluemix Container Service region. Kubernetes is available in two different IBM Bluemix Container Service regions, us-south and eu-central. To access these regions, use the optional `--host` flag when you initialize the container service. For eu-central, that would be 
    `bx cs init --host https://eu-central.containers.bluemix.net`

You can see the log in path in the docs: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cli_install.html#cs_cli_configure

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the above answer, you can also do another `bx cs init` after switching the bx region, and bx cs init will use the default host for the bx region you are in.  So if you don't want to learn the hosts needed, you can do it by changing bx regions, just remember to do `bx cs init` after.